# QT4 QgraphicsView not repainting in a "for cycle" of displaying many pages

Tags: qt4, qgraphicsview, repaint

I wrote a program to experiment with poppler pdf library.
I am able to display pdf pages into a graphicsView with a method:

```
void MainWindow::setPage(int newpage)
{

 pdfPage = document->page(newpage);
if (pdfPage == 0) {
  // ... error message ...
  return;
}

// Generate a QImage of the rendered page
image = pdfPage->renderToImage(100.0,100.0,0,0,pdfPage->pageSize().width(),pdfPage->pageSize().height());
if (image.isNull()) {
  // ... error message ...
  return;
}

pixmap=QPixmap::fromImage(image);
scene->clear();
scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
this->ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
this->ui->graphicsView->repaint(); //the same with show(), invalidate scene()
// after the usage, the page must be deleted
delete pdfPage;

}
```

with single call or in a slot for a control
but if I write a cycle like
for (i=0;i<200;i++) { setPage(i);}
nothing is displayed until the cycle gets to its end, and then just the last page is visible.
What's wrong?
I tried with msleep(500) in a custom thread class, and tried also calling paintEvent for graphicsView.
Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cause a widget to redraw itself in a loop. In order for a widget (or graphics item)  to draw itself, control must return to the event loop every time the appearance of the widget changes. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715920/qt-qgraphicsscene-not-updating-when-i-would-expect-it-to) and its answers for more information.